# Cannot move std::function into map

Tags: c++, templates, move-semantics

I have some Signal prototype class

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

template <class T>
class Signal
{
public:
    std::function<T> slot;
};
```

Next comes template singleton `SignalCollection` class, that automatically generates appropriate type for `Signal`

```
template <class T>
class SignalCollection
{
private:
    SignalCollection() {}
    SignalCollection(const SignalCollection&) = delete;
    SignalCollection& operator= (const SignalCollection&) = delete;
public:

    static SignalCollection& Instance()
    {
        static SignalCollection br{};
        return br;
    }

    std::map<std::string, T> signals_map;

    void add(T&& signal)
    {
        this->signals_map.insert(std::make_pair("a", std::forward<T>(signal)));
    }
};
```

and last I have a function that deduces `SignalCollection` type for some `Signal`

```
template<class T>
auto& get_collection_for_signal(T&& t)
{
    return SignalCollection<T>::Instance();
}
```

The problem is, that I can't add values to the map of collection. Here is main:

```
void foo()
{

}
void main()
{
    Signal<void()> sgl = Signal<void()>{}; //Create signal
    sgl.slot = foo;                       //add slot

    auto& t = get_collection_for_signal(sgl); //Get collection for this signal which is SignalCollection<Signal<void()>>

    t.add(sgl); //error 1
    t.signals_map["a"] = sgl; //error 2
}
```

Comment: Please copy-paste full error messages (from the "Output" tab, instead of the "Error List"), since ones that you show here, doesn't seem complete.

Comment: sorry I missed 
void foo()
{
}

in the top of code

Comment: 1) This is not what I was pointing out. 2) Now `//error 1` `//error 2` comments, doesn't make sense, due to the fact, that your question no longer contains any errors, that you get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is

```
template<class T>
auto& get_collection_for_signal(T&& t)
{
    return SignalCollection<T>::Instance();
}
```

When you call it like

```
auto& t = get_collection_for_signal(sgl);
```

`T` is deduced as `Signal<void()>&` and that means you return a `SignalCollection<Signal<void()>&>` which is not what you want.  What you need to do is remove the reference from the type.  You can do that using

```
template<class T>
auto& get_collection_for_signal(T&&)
{
    return SignalCollection<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>::Instance();
}
```

which removed the *cv* qualification and the reference from `T` (C++20 gives us `std::remove_cvref` so it can be done with a single helper).

You can also get the same behavior with

```
template<class T>
auto& get_collection_for_signal(T)
{
    return SignalCollection<T>::Instance();
}
```

This involves a lot less typing and gives you the same behavior since top level cv qualifications get striped out and it will never deduce a reference.

---

You also have an issue with your `add` function.

```
void add(T&& signal)
{
    this->signals_map.insert(std::make_pair("a", std::forward<T>(signal)));
}
```

isn't using a forwarding reference since `T` is part of the class type.  You need to make it it's own template to have a forwarding reference.  You can do that by changing it to

```
template<typename U>
void add(U&& signal)
{
    this->signals_map.insert(std::make_pair("a", std::forward<U>(signal)));
}
```

---

lastly

```
void main()
```

is **always** wrong.  `main()` is mandated to return an `int`.  Have a read through [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

`T&&` is not a forwarding reference if `T` is not deduced, and converse.

```
template<class T>
auto& get_collection_for_signal(T&& t)
```

`T` is deduced as a reference to `Signal<void()>` in your example use:

```
auto& t = get_collection_for_signal(sgl);
```

so it returns:

```
return SignalCollection<T>::Instance();
```

which is:

```
SignalCollection<Signal<void()>&>::Instance()
```

which is nonsense.

Brush up on forwarding references and l/rvalue references.  Every use of it in your code is wrong.

Design wise, you have useless types -- `Signal<T>` as written is a std function with baggage that does nothing -- global singletons, and type deduction creating global state.

I get what you are trying to do, but it is kin to wanting to make a fire engine out of straw.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are good at explaining the error, but I would recommend another solution to fix the problem.

I see that in your code you don't actually need a forwarding reference. You only use it for deduction. In that case, you can take your argument by `T const&`, which always will deduce a `T` without a reference.

```
template<class T>
auto& get_collection_for_signal(T const& t)
{
    return SignalCollection<T>::Instance();
}
```